# How can I add items in arraylist from a function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arraylist, addition

I have this function and I want to add this items in my arraylist. I know data.push(...) is not correct, so what it's the correct way?

```
          function addinfo(data) {
                var id = document.getElementById("courseid").value;
                var nm = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var yr = document.getElementById("year").value;
                var syll = document.getElementById("syllabus").value;
                var sem = document.getElementById("semester").value;
                var teach = document.getElementById("teaching").value;

                data.push(id,nm,yr,syll,sem,teach);
          }

          var data = [
              {
                courseid: "1",
                name: "Artificial Intelligence",
                year: "2021",
                syllabus: "3",
                semester: "2",
                teaching: "Johan"
              }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to push all these values as an object into the data array. You could achieve that by doing the following.
By giving the variables the same name as the keys in the object you can leave that out.

```
var data = [
  {
    courseid: "1",
    name: "Artificial Intelligence",
    year: "2021",
    syllabus: "3",
    semester: "2",
    teaching: "Johan"
  }
]

function addinfo(data) {
  var courseid = document.getElementById("courseid").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var syllabus = document.getElementById("syllabus").value;
  var semester = document.getElementById("semester").value;
  var teaching = document.getElementById("teaching").value;

  data.push({courseid,name,year,syllabus,semester,teaching});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addinfo(data) {
  data.push({
    courseid: document.getElementById("courseid").value,
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    year: document.getElementById("year").value,
    syllabus: document.getElementById("syllabus").value,
    semester: document.getElementById("semester").value,
    teaching: document.getElementById("teaching").value
  });
}
```

Comment: All of the document.getElementById(...) can be moved to a separate method so it looks simply : data.push (getDetails()) where getDetails() method would return the object as necessary.

Comment: @SRChaitanya Good point. Separation of concerns in action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a function that adds according to element ids stored in an array. Errors are not handled.

```
const fields = ["courseid", "name", "year", "syllabus", "semester", "teaching"];

function addinfo(anyFieldList, data) {
  const dataItem = {};
  for (let aField of anyFieldList){
    dataItem[aField] = document.getElementById(aField).value;
  }
  data.push(dataItem);
}

let data = [
  {
    courseid: "1",
    name: "Artificial Intelligence",
    year: "2021",
    syllabus: "3",
    semester: "2",
    teaching: "Johan"
  }
]
```